# The code repeats the table headings :

Tags: php, mysql

I have a code which writes data from the database to ms document : it works pretty well but it repeats the Table  headings like this :
Subscriber's Name   Subscriber's Account No.    S-Card No.  Decoder No. Contact No  Date Installed  Activation Date
Timer                   0   ..
Subscriber's Name   Subscriber's Account No.    S-Card No.  Decoder No. Contact No  Date Installed  Activation Date
Musajhujasasa           903343434342        2013    ..
Subscriber's Name   Subscriber's Account No.    S-Card No.  Decoder No. Contact No  Date Installed  Activation Date

But I want it to display like this 
Subscriber's Name   Subscriber's Account No.    S-Card No.  Decoder No. Contact No  Date Installed  Activation Date
Timer   676737363743    Vc 67676    Dc456   07855625426 2013    . 2013
Musa    7878787878  Vc3454. Dc56    089898892   2013    2013
Musajhujasasa   87u8u78u8u  Vc4565  Dc786   089887387   2013    2013
Dread   S77878787879    Vc 45454    Dc5653  078563536   2013    2013

```
   <?php
   #this connects to my database
   include("db.inc.php"); 
   ?>
       <?php
     $query='SELECT  * 
    from clientinfo';
    $result = mysql_query($query,$con) or die (mysql_error($con));
        $fp = fopen("report.doc", 'w+'); 

    while($record = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $firstname = $record['firstname'];
        $refno = $record['refno'];
        $smartcard = $record['smartcard'];
        $decoderno = $record['decoderno'];
        $cell = $record['cell'];
        $date= $record['date'];
     #create word document starts here
    $str ="<table border=\"1\"><tr><td><b>Subscriber's Name</b></td><td>  <b>     Subscriber's      Account No.</b></td> <td><b>S-Card No.</b></td><td><b>Decoder     No.</b>    </td>
    <td><b>Contact No</b></td><td><b>Date Installed</b></td><td><b>Activation Date</b></td>
    </tr>
     </tr><tr><td>$firstname</td><td >$refno</td><td >$smartcard</td><td>$decoderno</td>
    <td>$cell</td><td >$date</td><td >..</td>
    </tr></table>";
       fwrite($fp, $str);  
     }
       fclose($fp);
    ?>
```

Comment: Please, don't use mysql_* functions in new code. They are no longer maintained and are officially deprecated. Learn about prepared statements instead, and use PDO or MySQLi

Answer (score 0):

It repeats because the headings are inside while loop.

```
  <?php
   #this connects to my database
   include("db.inc.php"); 
   ?>
       <?php
     $query='SELECT  * 
    from clientinfo';
    $result = mysql_query($query,$con) or die (mysql_error($con));
        $fp = fopen("report.doc", 'w+'); 

$str ="<table border=\"1\"><tr><td><b>Subscriber's Name</b></td><td>  <b>     Subscriber's      Account No.</b></td> <td><b>S-Card No.</b></td><td><b>Decoder No.</b>    </td>";

while($record = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $firstname = $record['firstname'];
        $refno = $record['refno'];
        $smartcard = $record['smartcard'];
        $decoderno = $record['decoderno'];
        $cell = $record['cell'];
        $date= $record['date'];
     #create word document starts here
   $str.="
    <td><b>Contact No</b></td><td><b>Date Installed</b></td><td><b>Activation Date</b></td>
    </tr>
     </tr><tr><td>$firstname</td><td >$refno</td><td >$smartcard</td><td>$decoderno</td>
    <td>$cell</td><td >$date</td><td >..</td>
    </tr></table>";


fwrite($fp, $str);  
     }
       fclose($fp);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your doing mistake in looping,

```
     $str = "<table border=\"1\"><tr><td><b>Subscriber's Name</b></td><td>  <b>     Subscriber's      Account No.</b></td> <td><b>S-Card No.</b></td><td><b>Decoder     No.</b>    </td>
    <td><b>Contact No</b></td><td><b>Date Installed</b></td><td><b>Activation Date</b></td>
    </tr>
     </tr>";
   fwrite($fp, $str);  
    while($record = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $firstname = $record['firstname'];
        $refno = $record['refno'];
        $smartcard = $record['smartcard'];
        $decoderno = $record['decoderno'];
        $cell = $record['cell'];
        $date= $record['date'];
     #create word document starts here
    $str ="<tr><td>$firstname</td><td >$refno</td><td >$smartcard</td><td>$decoderno</td>
    <td>$cell</td><td >$date</td><td >..</td>
    </tr>";
    fwrite($fp, $str);  
     }
      $str = "</table>";
     fwrite($fp, $str);
     fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     <?php
   #this connects to my database
   include("db.inc.php"); 
   ?>
       <?php
     $query='SELECT  * 
    from clientinfo';
    $result = mysql_query($query,$con) or die (mysql_error($con));
        $fp = fopen("report.doc", 'w+'); 
     if(mysql_num_rows($result))
     {    

    $str ="<table border=\"1\"><tr><td><b>Subscriber's Name</b></td><td>  <b>     Subscriber's      Account No.</b></td> <td><b>S-Card No.</b></td><td><b>Decoder     No.</b>    </td>
    <td><b>Contact No</b></td><td><b>Date Installed</b></td><td><b>Activation Date</b></td></tr>";
    while($record = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $firstname = $record['firstname'];
        $refno = $record['refno'];
        $smartcard = $record['smartcard'];
        $decoderno = $record['decoderno'];
        $cell = $record['cell'];
        $date= $record['date'];
     #create word document starts here

     $str .= "<tr><td>$firstname</td><td >$refno</td><td >$smartcard</td><td>$decoderno</td>
    <td>$cell</td><td >$date</td><td >..</td>
    </tr>";

     }
     $str .= "</table>";
      fwrite($fp, $str);  
     }
       fclose($fp);
    ?>
```

Comment: The above updated code will solve your issue. Please revert for any clarifications

Answer (score 0):

In your code you create table and table heading within while loop so it is repeating.. You have to put code of table and table heading outside of while loop. Please try code given below.

```
  $str = "<table border=\"1\"><tr><td><b>Subscriber's Name</b></td><td>  <b>     Subscriber's Account No.</b></td> <td><b>S-Card No.</b></td><td><b>Decoder No.</b></td>
<td><b>Contact No</b></td><td><b>Date Installed</b></td><td><b>Activation Date</b></td>
</tr>";

 while($record = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $firstname = $record['firstname'];
        $refno = $record['refno'];
        $smartcard = $record['smartcard'];
        $decoderno = $record['decoderno'];
        $cell = $record['cell'];
        $date= $record['date'];

        #create word document starts here
        $str .=  "<tr><td>$firstname</td><td >$refno</td><td >$smartcard</td>  
        <td>$decoderno</td><td>$cell</td><td >$date</td><td >..</td></tr>";

     }
    $str .= "</table>";
    fwrite($fp, $str);
```

thanks